# Multiple Users with Login Session

Tags: php, mysql, session

Currently I am having a bit of trouble. I have my website working over a router, but it appears when me and my sister are on my website together we are logged into the same account/user.

example: Say, I logged out. Then my sister is logged out, or I login, then she is logged in with the same account as I.

I know there must be something wrong with my sessions, and currently I'm trying to learn and think about what would it be like if there were more than one users online interacting and doing things. Honestly, I'm just barely scratched the surface of sessions, and I'm trying to learn what happens when multiple users are online at once.

and I have looked at the other Q&As on here, but I haven't had to much luck finding anything helpful on this subject. I wouldn't mind any help or suggestions, any points to flaws in my basic system.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_id("userID");

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
  $_SESSION['login'] = false;
} elseif($_SESSION['login'] === true) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['l-user']}' LIMIT 1";
$set = mysqli_query($db->connection, $query);
$get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($set);

$_SESSION['l-avatar'] = "{$get['avatar']}";
}


class Registery {

  // variables
  public $login;
  public $user;
  private $reg;
  private $log;

  public function register() {

    $db = new MySQLDatabase();

    if($_SESSION['login'] === false) {
        $s_user = strip_tags($_POST['user']);
        $s_pass = strip_tags($_POST['pass']);
        $s_bio = strip_tags($_POST['content'], "<p><b><i><img><br><a>");
        $s_gend = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);
        $s_age = strip_tags($_POST['age']);
        $s_u = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $s_user);
        $s_p = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $s_pass);
        $s_b = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $s_bio);
        $s_g = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $s_gend);
        $s_a = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $s_age);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, content, tag, gender, rank, age, date, time) VALUES (NULL, '{$s_u}', '".sha1($s_p)."', '{$s_b}', 'I\'m new! And my name is {$s_u}', '{$s_g}', 'member', '{$s_a}', CURDATE(), NOW())";
        $this->reg = mysqli_query($db->connection, $sql);

        if($this->reg === true) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['l-user'] = "{$s_u}";
        }
    }
}

public function confirm_reg() {
    if($this->reg === true) {
        $success = "<div class=\"success\">";
        $success .= "<p><b><i class=\"fi-info\"></i></b> Successfully registered.</p>";
        $success .= "</div>";
        echo "{$success}";
    } else {
        $error = "<div class=\"error\">";
        $error .= "<p><b><i class=\"fi-info\"></i></b> Failed to register.<br /><b>NOTE:</b> You may have entered a username that already exists.</p>";
        $error .= "</div>";
        echo "{$error}";
    }
}

public function login() {

    $db = new MYSQLDatabase();

    if($_SESSION['login'] === false) {
        $s_user = strip_tags($_POST['user']);
        $s_pass = strip_tags($_POST['pass']);
        $s_u = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $s_user);
        $s_p = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $s_pass);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$s_u}' AND password='".sha1($s_p)."' LIMIT 1";
        $this->log = mysqli_query($db->connection, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($this->log) === 1) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['l-user'] = "{$s_u}";
        }
    }
}

public function confirm_log() {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($this->log) === 1) {
        $success = "<div class=\"success\">";
        $success .= "<p><b><i class=\"fi-info\"></i></b> Successfully logged in.</p>";
        $success .= "</div>";
        echo "{$success}";
    } else {
        $error = "<div class=\"error\">";
        $error .= "<p><b><i class=\"fi-info\"></i></b> Failed to login.<br /><b>NOTE:</b> You entered the wrong username or password, make sure your capslock is off.</p>";
        $error .= "</div>";
        echo "{$error}";
    }
}

public function logout() {
    $_SESSION['login'] = false;
    $_SESSION['l-user'] = "";
}

} // end of class

$user = new Registery();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a unique session id for each session.

Comment: Well that's what I figured, but I'm not having any good luck about _how_ to set a unique `session_id` for each user.